# Image to fit whole width of parent div that has 100vh without stretching the image even if div is wider than image

Tags: html, css, image

I have a div with a width of 97% and a height of 100vh to fit the height of the div to the windows height. This is working very well.

Now I want to place an image inside this div. This image shall fill the width of the div but not more that the images height allows, without overflowing, being cut or stretching.

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <p class="title">This is a title!</p>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x600.png">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried this css:

```
img {
    max-width:90%;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
div {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    width:97%;
    height:100vh;
}
```

But this will not expand the image to more than its width of 800px. So this won't fill the width of the div.

I tried this css:

```
img {
    width:90%;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
div {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    width:97%;
    height:100vh;
}
```

But the image will overflow vertically.

How can I do that?

Comment: I think you need to be more clear on *This image shall fill the width of the div but not more that the images height allows*. Given the example image, I interpret this as: an image of 800x600 is not allowed to be wider than 600, which basically involves either clipping or scaling (which is also 'stretching', but retaining ratio).

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```css
div {
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-width:1px;
    width:97%;
    height:100vh;
}
p {margin:0;}
img {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:calc(100% - 18px);
    object-fit:contain;
    object-position:top;  /*or object-position:left top; if you want the image aligned to left*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="title">This is a title!</p>

    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x600.png">

</div>
```

**EDITED**

Comment: Image will overflow because of: `<p class="title">This is a title!</p>`

Comment: I have edited my answer. however it will online work if you know the height of the `<p>` element. if not you may need to use `javascript`

Comment: it's still overflowing because in the calc() operation @AlvaroMenéndez didn't take into account th <p> margins. So, you can change the height of the height of the image to `calc(100% - 18px - 16px - 16px);` or set `margin: 0;` to the `<p>`

Comment: Ty Carlo. I edited again my answer adding `margin:0` to `<p>`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a img but set a background to your div
Example:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p class="title">This is a title!</p>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```css
div {
      width:97%;
      height:100vh;
      background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/800x600.png");
      background-size: cover;
  }
```

Comment: But how to place the image below `This is a title!`?

Comment: Make a div with background under the title, at least your image will always be the same size

Comment: This will cut the image either vertically or horizontally, depending on the window size.

Comment: Play with background-size and background-repeat
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 0):

This is how interpret what you need: *(text removed, had faulty logic)*...

**update**

You've at least got to appreciate my perseverance...

The default values of the 'Flexbox Layout' mechanism did the trick.

- Parent `.wrapper` div needs to be `display: flex` as by default FBL child elements have `flex-grow: 0`, this prevents the image from growing outside the parent
- have `.wrapper` pull the content to its side by `align-items: flex-start` (instead of the default `stretch`)
- by default `img` has `width: auto; height: auto`, making only `height: 100%` will cause the image to grow in size retaining its ratio
- setting its `max-width: 100%` will keep it inside the parent (combined with default `flex-grow: 0`)
- `object-fit: contain` will make ensure the proper ratio
- `object-position: 0 0` will attach the image to the top/left corner of its content box (as opposed to default `center` or `50% 50%`). You test this by disabling the CSS as you may prefer the default.

Result is that the image resizes based on its height and ratio, attaches to the text and stays inside the parent container. No cutting, clipping, no ratio stretching, no overflow, what all not... and no JS...

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;  /* a column of 2 rows (text and image)*/ 
    align-items: flex-start; /* horizontal align (default = 'stretch') */

    border-style: solid;
    border-width:1px;
    width : 97%;
    height: 100vh;
}
.img {
    height: 100%;           /* always full height image (default is 'width: auto') */
    max-width: 100%;        /* don't go outside parent container */

/*    max-height: calc(100% - 50px); /* don't go outside parent container */
/* only required when '.wrapper' has no 'align-items: flex-start' */

    object-fit: contain;    /* no cutting or stretch */
    object-position: 0 0;   /* move to top/left postion of content box (default is center) */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="title">This is a title!</p>
    <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x600.png">
</div>
```

Comment: The image doesn't expand if the div is higher or wider than the image.